# unity begin touch not detecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect when someone has touched the screen. To do this I have the following code in the update function:

```
    print(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began); //Prints false

    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        print(Input.GetTouch(0).phase); //Prints stationary
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        currentTrail.transform.position = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        rb.position = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        print("touched down"); //Doesnt get called
        circleCollider.enabled = false;
        currentTrail = Instantiate(trail, transform);
        isCutting = true;
    }
```

So as you can see my touch began if statment doesnt get called.

The screen is detecting the touch but its phase is stationary and never starts on begin.

Comment: Which function are you calling this code from? Which platform ?

Comment: the update function, what do you mean which platform sorry? its 3d game

Comment: Android, iOS....or you are running it on the Editor

Comment: oh android, galaxy s7 to be precise

Comment: I think that it works. You likely missed the log because `TouchPhase.Began` should be true **once** only until the finger is released.. This means that "touched down" will show once only. Can you download **Unity Remote 5** on your Android device. From Unity Editor, go to Edit->Project Settings->Editor and select Android then connect your phone to your computer. Click play on the Editor and touch your phone. "touched down" should print **once**. If you don't then there is an issue with your code

Comment: Thats exactly what im doing, its 100% not getting called, even once. Ive tried taking he first if statment out so it should print "touched down" when it goes into the 2nd if statment but it never does

Comment: Can you do what I said with "Unity Remote 5" and tell me the result

Comment: Yes i can try it that way, atm ive connected my device directly but ill download this 1 second

Comment: @Programmer ok so apparently the first line of the 2nd if statment is throwing a null error which is why the print isnt called but it did actually return began whne i used unity remote 5. Thanks :D

Comment: Good. It's always good to make sure the code works in the Editor before building it and lunching in on standalone builds. It saves time. I assume you can fix the current null issue. If yes then happy coding!